# Python+Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.x, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь вытащить значение параметров (IP,маска,шлюз) в переменные для записи в файл, пока не выходит - ниже пример кода и результат. Пробовал метод `ip_addr=driver.find_element_by_id("ip").GetText()` - не помогло .[image: Сама страница]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
main_title=driver.get("http://192.168.1.88")
Man_int=driver.find_element_by_id("header-management").click()
ip_addr=driver.find_element_by_id("ip")
print(ip_addr)
selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="193f58f6-8096-45b8-a2d9-36ae3b677b3c", element="a900c748-16df-4242-9898-a0a59e02b022")>
```

Comment: print(ip_addr.get_attribute('value'))

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь вывести весь элемент, а вам нужно текстовое значение элемента, сделайте это так:

```
print(ip_addr.text)
```

Comment: К сожалению с этим методом в результате выходит пустое значение